# cryptsetup error while doing sudo-apt upgrade

Tags: ubiquity

```
Setting up ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork (2.21.63.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubiquity:
 ubiquity depends on cryptsetup; however:
  Package cryptsetup is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubiquity (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubiquity-frontend-gtk:
 ubiquity-frontend-gtk depends on ubiquity (= 2.21.63.4); however:
  Package ubiquity is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubiquity-frontend-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.7) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/unattended-upgrades ...
Synchronizing state of unattended-upgrades.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable unattended-upgrades
Setting up unity-control-center-faces (15.04.0+16.04.20170214-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up vino (3.8.1-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Setting up xfonts-utils (1:7.7+3ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up xserver-common (2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 (1:7.7+16ubuntu3~16.04.1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04 (1:7.7+16ubuntu3~16.04.1) ...
Setting up xul-ext-ubufox (3.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up appmenu-qt5 (0.3.0+16.04.20170216-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up kpartx (0.5.0+git1.656f8865-5ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up kpartx-boot (0.5.0+git1.656f8865-5ubuntu2.5) ...
update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media
Setting up liblouis-data (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up liblouis9:amd64 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up oxideqt-codecs:amd64 (1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-louis (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
Setting up evince (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libmetacity-private3a:amd64 (1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up metacity (1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up nautilus (1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu6) ...
Setting up shotwell (0.22.0+git20160108.r1.f2fb1f7-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up apport-gtk (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10) ...
Setting up libreoffice-common (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/bash_completion.d/libreoffice.sh ...
Setting up libreoffice-style-galaxy (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-style-breeze (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libnss3-nssdb (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libnss3:amd64 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libnss3-1d:amd64 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-core (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-base-core (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-calc (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-gtk (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-gnome (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-writer (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-draw (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-impress (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-ogltrans (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-pdfimport (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up python3-uno (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-math (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
Setting up liboxideqtcore0:amd64 (1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up liboxideqtquick0:amd64 (1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 (1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.78ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cryptsetup
 ubiquity
 ubiquity-frontend-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

New to Linux, so I am lost!

Answer (score 1):

Before running the upgrade again, you could try to configure cryptsetup with `sudo dpkg --configure cryptsetup` from the command line. If that doesn't help, you could try to configure all packages which still need configuration with `sudo dpkg --configure --pending` before trying to run the upgrade again.

That being said, if you're new you can also use an application with a GUI once you've solved this problem. I like "synaptic", but you probably would need to install that first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion and received the following error: 
sudo dpkg --configure cryptsetup
dpkg: error processing package cryptsetup (--configure):
 package cryptsetup is already installed and configured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cryptsetup

Comment: If  `sudo dpkg --configure --pending` also fails to help you, it might be helpful to post the error messages you receive there so we can hopefully see what the problem is.

Comment: Also to note, I am booting from a USB and am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
Here are screenshots of the error:
https://pasteboard.co/GL2LJjd.png
https://pasteboard.co/GL2M4Kz.png

Also, a pastebin: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25570577/
I can upload the entire log, if needed

Comment: anyone with some ideas?

Comment: You didn't tell us if you tried the second command I suggested. If you don't know what to do, I suggest that that you try and let us know the results.

Comment: Neither suggestion worked. So the problem persists: https://pastebin.com/RFc3auUb

This last command  you suggested did not do anything.
I found a workaround/temporary solution but it is a lengthy process to implement. If there is a more permanent solution, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has changed: In a comment, you're writing that `sudo dpkg --configure --pending` doesn't output anything. Therefore, the error messages you pasted into your question do no longer appear in that particular way. Your original problem is gone. You're now seemingly experiencing a different one.

You could try `sudo apt-get check` to check for dependency problems. `sudo apt-get -f install` will try to fix dependency problems automatically.